# Razor engine not happy with my inline code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This code is copied directly from Scott Gu's blog (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx):

```
Hello @name, the year is @DateTime.Now.Year
```

When I try this, it works:

```
@foreach (var post in ViewBag.Posts)
{
    @post.Title<br />
}
```

But when I try this, the code highlighter gets the whole thing as one Razor declaration and the compiler fails:

```
@foreach (var post in ViewBag.Posts)
{
    @post.Title, by @post.Author<br />
}
```

I get `Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ','`.  Again, with just `@post.Title<br />` it compiles just fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the content isn't **obviously** either language or content, you need to help it decide:

```
@foreach (var post in ViewBag.Posts)
{
    @:@post.Title, by @post.Author<br />
}
```

or:

```
@foreach (var post in ViewBag.Posts)
{
    <text>@post.Title, by @post.Author<br /></text>
}
```

or

```
@foreach (var post in ViewBag.Posts)
{
    <text>
    @post.Title, by @post.Author<br />
    </text>
}
```